# How to create an offline webpage if connection to the server is lost

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

Firstly, I'm not sure whether this is possible and a Google search doesn't seem to provide much in the way of a solution. However ...

> Is it possible to create a .html page which displays if the connection to the hosting server (apache/linux) is lost or the MYSQL service goes down?

So if either of the two situations should occur - then a page will be displayed as follows

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> *Sitename* - currently offline</title>
  <meta name="description" content=" .. //">
  <meta name="author" content=" .. //">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
</head>
<body>
   <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
   <?php  
         // some PHP code
   ?>

  <p>  We're currently experiencing some technical difficulties with our site. 
   The issue should be fixed shortly - we apologise for any inconvenience caused. 
   Please try to access the site again later. 

   Thank you. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The function would need to check the connection to the server when an attempt is made to access the site. If the connection is broken then display the above HTML.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If the connection between the client and server is gone how are you going to serve said page?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Offline

Comment: You would have to load the complete site (all webpages) Up front and use jQuery and ajax to still be able to navigate through the site. Basicly retrieve the whole site to client-side.

Comment: @TomKriek - Can you flesh that out in an answer please?

Comment: That's way too much work to do in a few minutes. You need to think unreasonably for this one. Think about loading the different webpages in jQuery variables. Everything. Then make onclick handlers for menu buttons and links and let the different pages load in when they are clicked. See the different jQueries to edit elements on a page. With the help of Ajax you could do a check to see if the server is live and if it returns false switch to the jQuery setup. Be sure to not include your source PHP code in the jQuery variables as this could compromise your whole site. Good luck.

Comment: This is highly unpractical and you are probably better off just doing an Ajax request and then update some text that the site is offline. Or resort to a 3rd party like cloudflare.

Comment: @TomKriek - thanks I'll have a look at Cloudfare to see what the 'AlwaysOnline' Service provides.

Comment: "... if the connection to the hosting server (apache/linux) is lost"

You'd need to handle this on the front-end of the site, via JS, intercepting any navigation to other pages on your site, or other requests, such as AJAX calls, to check if the connection has been severed, then display a message (such as in a modal box).

"or the MYSQL service goes down"

This could be handled server-side when your PHP logic connects to the MySQL DB. We have no idea how you're connecting to the DB, but there should be some logic that attempts to connect, then displays your desired message on failure.

Comment: Be aware that they will store a static version of your site all server interation is disabled. Should your site not be able to be reached they will switch to a hosting of theirs and display the last available state of your site.

Comment: "if the connection to the hosting server (apache/linux) is lost" is too vague. re MySQL: In the controller for the webapp, if you detect the DB connection is down, return a 503 HTTP response, and configure the webserver to display your custom page for 503 errors (probably all 50x errors).

Comment: @jpw - My vagueness is due to no knowledge in this area. I appreciate your comment (and the other comments above) but I have no idea how to implement any of the suggestions. A nice tidy fully formed answer would be mucho appreciated! Demonstrating how some of these suggestions might be coded? How to return a 503 HTTP response .. etc . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a .html page which displays if the connection
>   to the hosting server (apache/linux) is lost

Assuming you mean someone's network connection goes down half-way through surfing your site, as per some of the comments on the question, you could kind-of do some sort of solution in JavaScript but it's just a bad idea.  You are implying that there's a problem with the server when there isn't.  Let the browser do it's thing in this case, as it's more informative to the user and should present helpful hints to help them fix the actual problem.

If you mean the server has gone down entirely, you need some kind of solution like CloudFlare.

> or the MYSQL service goes down?

Yes. For any response which might need the DB, if you have detected the DB going away, **before you send any other HTTP headers** do this;

```
  header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
  echo 'Your error HTML.';
```

... or a "503 - Service unavailable"

Comment: Thanks for your answer - so presuming that the server has gone down completely ... is there anyway to show an offline message to the user trying to access the site? Without using a paid service like CloudFlare.

Comment: @aphextwix No, i think you are missunderstanding how http works. When a browser requests a resource(webpage), the server sends it. If the server is broken, it cant respond, so the browser gets nothing back, and handles it however it chooses (normally a error message). The javascript solutions suggested would only work for a user who has started browsing you site **before** the server went down, any new visitors would still get a error. Cloudfare has a free plan that might solve your problem